# Elasticsearch runtime field total with if statment

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two inventory fields:

- inventory.warehouse1.availableInventory: 10
- inventory.warehouse2.availableInventory: 20

I need to make a query with sum of these two fields and make a boost if total > 0.

I try to make runtime total field but get an error.

```
PUT product/_mapping
{
 "runtime": {
 "total": {
  "type": "long",
  "script": {
    "source": "emit(doc['inventory.warehouse1.availableInventory'].value + 
     doc['inventory.warehouse2.availableInventory'].value)"
   }
  }
 }
}

Error: 

 "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [runtime : 
{total={type=long, script=. 
  {source=emit(doc['inventory.warehouse1.availableInventory'].value + 
   doc['inventory.warehouse2.availableInventory'].value)}}}]"
```

How to make sum of two fields and make condition > 0?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your emit() is correct. The error is actually on trying to set up the runtime field itself.

I encountered this same error today and just figured it out. I was running Elasticsearch 7.4.0. **Upgrading to the newest in the 7.x line (7.17.6) fixed it for me.**

FWIW, I was using a Docker setup, with docker-compose. The version tags for available Docker images only include specific versions, so you can't just pull and get the latest - you need to explicitly specify the exact version you want in the docker-compose.yml file.

Hope that helps!